# Searching for a string in a file and saving the results

Tags: python, string, file, find, save

I have a few quite large text files with data on them. I need to find a string that repeats from the data and the string will always have an id number after it. I will need to then save that number.

Ive done some simple scripting with python but I am unsure where to start from with this or if python is even a good idea for this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Show sample data, show your attempt at solving your own problem, and show expected output.

Comment: It would be helpful if you offered an example in code of what you have tried as well as an example of your large text files, string, and expected output. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Since you haven't provided any attempt with your code nor a sample file, this question is liable to **downvotes**.

Answer (score 0):

I will post more information next time (my bad), but I managed to get something to work that should do it for me.

```
import re
with open("test.txt", "r") as opened:
    text = opened.read()
output = re.findall(r"\bdata........", text)
out_str = ",".join(output)
print (out_str)
#with open("output.txt", "w") as outp:
    #outp.write(out_str)
```